# Graph Schedule + Shifts API: MS-APP-ACTS-AS header needs to be set for application context requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am having issues running a GET against both the schedules and shifts v1.0 API. The documentation on the MS KB doesn't indicate that this is in preview any more, so I'm unsure what we're doing wrong here. The API is running with an app-only auth token

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwSO2.png)

Currently we are doing prelim testing via postman to ensure we can use the API correctly.

The app in question has been given the following permissions:

Schedule.Read.All

Schedule.ReadWrite.All

We can view the teamId information correctly at https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{{TeamId}}, but schedules or schedules/shifts returns the error

Based on a previous answer I saw, I added the MS-APP-ACT-AS header with a UserId to act as, but it returned the same error

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this header instead:

```
MS-APP-ACTS-AS
```

In your question you wrote:

```
MS-APP-ACT-AS
```

(Missing the 'S')